# List of Tables and databases in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

How do I get a list of databases + metadata on a server and the tables they own + tables metadata in **single** view?

Any way to join `sys.databases` and `sys.tables`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to import them or just view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All and thank you for your help!

I have been pointed to the following article which provide quite neat solution:

[ALL tables in all DB's](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/alltables/)

```
    ------------
-- Microsoft SQL Server database meta data - list of all tables in database
------------
USE AdventureWorks2008; 
-- SQL list all tables using system view sys.objects 
SELECT   SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), 
         TableName = name 
FROM     sys.objects 
WHERE    TYPE = 'U' 
         AND is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY SchemaName, 
         TableName 
GO 

/* Partial results 

SchemaName        TableName 
dbo               AWBuildVersion 
dbo               Category 
dbo               DatabaseLog 
dbo               ErrorLog 
dbo               SubCategory 
dbo               sysdiagrams 
HumanResources    Department 
HumanResources    Employee 
HumanResources    EmployeeDepartmentHistory 
HumanResources    EmployeePayHistory 
*/


-- T-SQL alternative: using a different system view - sys.tables 
SELECT   SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), 
         TableName = name 
FROM     sys.tables 
ORDER BY SchemaName, 
         TableName
GO
------------


-- MSSQL information_schema views - ANSI 92 SQL compatible 
SELECT * 
FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE    table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, 
         TABLE_NAME 
/* Partial results 

TABLE_CATALOG     TABLE_SCHEMA      TABLE_NAME                    TABLE_TYPE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesOrderHeader              BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason   BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesPerson                   BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesPersonQuotaHistory       BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesReason                   BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesTaxRate                  BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesTerritory                BASE TABLE 
AdventureWorks    Sales             SalesTerritoryHistory         BASE TABLE
*/

------------
--- SQL list all table in all databases on PRODSRV\SQL2008 SQL Server instance
DECLARE  @CMD VARCHAR(1024) 

CREATE TABLE #TableList ( 
  DatabaseName SYSNAME, 
  SchemaName   SYSNAME, 
  TableName    SYSNAME) 

SET @CMD = 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME()DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),
             NAME FROM SYS.TABLES' 
PRINT @CMD -- test & debug

-- T-SQL insert exec undocumented system procedure
INSERT INTO #TableList 
EXEC SP_MSFOREACHDB  @CMD

DELETE FROM #TableList
WHERE  DatabaseName IN ('master','msdb','tempdb','model') 

SELECT * 
FROM   #TableList 
ORDER BY DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName
GO
/* Partial results

DatabaseName            SchemaName  TableName
AdventureWorks2008      Sales       SalesTerritoryHistory
AdventureWorks2008      Sales       ShoppingCartItem
AdventureWorks2008      Sales       SpecialOffer
*/

DROP TABLE #TableList 
GO
------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the needed selects into a variable and execute the SQL

```
Declare @a varchar(max)
Select @a=''
select @a=@a + 'select '''+name+''' as DB, *  from ['+name+'].sys.tables' + CHAR(10) + 'UNION '
from master.dbo.sysdatabases

Set @a=SUBSTRING(@a,1,len(@a)-Len('UNION '))
EXEC( @a)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach would be create a view that will retrieve all
of the table names. Here is a stored procedure that will build that
view. You'll need to re-create the view if you add or remove any new
databases but the view should stay good as long as your databases
remains static.

Loop:

```
INSERT INTO t_fo_databases
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%SITE' ORDER BY name

DECLARE @DBs as varchar(MAX)
WHILE (SELECT TOP 1 names FROM t_fo_databases) LIKE '%SITE'

BEGIN
SET @DBs = (SELECT TOP 1 names FROM t_fo_databases)
PRINT @DBs
USE [master]
DELETE FROM t_fo_Databases WHERE names = @DBs
END
```

View which will retrieve table names

```
CREATE PROC sp_BuildDBTablesView

as

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views WHERE TABLE_NAME =
'vw_DBTables')
DROP TABLE vw_DBTables

DECLARE @CreateView varchar(8000)
SET @CreateView = 'CREATE VIEW vw_DBTables

as

'

SELECT name
INTO    #DBs
FROM sysDatabases

DECLARE @DBName varchar(100)

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #DBs) 0
BEGIN

SET @DBName = (SELECT min(name) FROM #DBs)

SET @CreateView = @CreateView + 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBName +
'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' + CHAR(13) + 'UNION' + CHAR(13)

DELETE  #DBs WHERE name = @DBName
END

SET @CreateView = LEFT(@CreateView, LEN(@CreateView) - 6) --- Take
off the last UNION

PRINT @CreateView

EXEC master..sp_SQLExec @CreateView

DROP TABLE #DBs

GO
```

Now, anytime you wish to view the tables just run:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.vw_DBTables
```

And you'll get the entire list.

I hope that helps.